# Is there a way in TypeScript to differentiate between undefined and a missing property?

Tags: typescript

Referencing the snippet below, I would like to be able to call `f` only with an object having a single property. Typescript should complain about additional properties, even when set to `undefined`.

```js
interface A {
  a: number;
  b?: never;
}

interface B {
  a?: never;
  b: number;
}

const f = (arg: A | B) => {};

// OK
f({ a: 0 });

// Error: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.
f({ a: 0, b: 0 });

// OK, but I would like to have an error
f({ a: 0, b: undefined });
```

In my case `f` is a [useReducer dispatcher](https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/react/useReducer#dispatch) which if called with `{ a: 0, b: undefined }` would set the property `b` of my component state to `undefined`, while if called with `{ a: 0 }` would leave the property `b` alone.

There is no reason why I would ever dispatch an `{ a: 0, b: undefined }` action, but still, is there a way to have TypeScript covering my shoulders?

Comment: You can add a check for missing field using the "in" keyword. typescript looks at missing field as an undefined no matter what.

Comment: Enable `exactOptionalPropertyTypes`

Comment: @vexingCoder but the check is just control flow inside the dispatcher, I would still be able to call the dispatcher with additional properties. It solves the problem of not messing up with the state though, thank you!

Comment: @caTS this is probably the right solution here, I am just not sure if enabling the flag would cause problems in other places, but I am going for it. Thank you very much!

Comment: If you've got the type `{a?: undefined}` then it will accept `undefined` even if `--exactOptionalPropertyTypes` is enabled.  If you don't want to accept `undefined` then you should remove `undefined` from the domain of the property type.

Comment: @jcalz I enabled the flag and everithing works as I want. If what you mean is that having an object literal with only optional `undefined` properties would cause problems, well that's not a problem in my case because every object in the union has at least (actually exactly one) required property typed other than `undefined`.

Comment: "I enabled the flag and everything works as I want"  Then your code here isn't a [mre] because [the flag has zero effect on it](https://tsplay.dev/w17Lym).  Your code here is `{a?: undefined}` and not `{a?: never}`.  Those are the same type and appear as `{a?: undefined}` when `--exactOptionalPropertyTypes` is off, but observably different when the flag is on. Probably "everything works" because you actually have the analog of `{a?: never}` and not `{a?: undefined}` in your code. Could you [edit] the code example to change `undefined` to `never`? If not, why not?

Comment: @jcalz so if I understand correctly, the flag would fix `{a?: never}` but not `{a?: undefined}`, is that what you are saying? Anyway by having a closer look at my type: yes, it looks like I actually have `never` rather than `undefined`. I generate the union with this utility: [RequireExactlyOne](https://github.com/sindresorhus/type-fest/blob/846f4dbf44e3c5151f778f6cc755a49c238e7bea/source/require-exactly-one.d.ts#L33) which has a `Record<>` with a `never` as second argument.

Comment: Right, that's what I'm saying.  Anyone who writes out `{a?: undefined}` presumably *intends* `undefined` to be a valid property value.  So, given that you actually have `never`, could you please [edit] your example code to be that?  Or I can do it, if you'd prefer.  Once it's edited, then the answer to the question as asked would be "turn on `--exactOptionalPropertyTypes` to get this behavior" (and someone should write that answer... you? me? @caTS?)

Comment: @jcalz it would be nice if you could write an answer for future people with the same doubt. And also I leave you the burden of editing the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is true that the default behavior is to treat [optional properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties) as if a missing property is the same as a present property whose value is `undefined`.  Indeed, the compiler will automatically add `undefined` to the domain of an optional property:

```
type Foo = {
    x?: string,
    y: string
}

/* type Foo = {
    x?: string | undefined;
    y: string;
} */

const foo: Foo = { y: "x" };
foo.x // string | undefined
foo.x = undefined; // okay
```

This is mostly fine for reading properties, since indeed get an `undefined` value from a missing property. But for writing properties, this is less optimal, as it allows `undefined` where most people wouldn't expect it to be allowed.

---

If you really don't like this, you could enable [the `--exactOptionalPropertyTypes` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#exact-optional-property-types---exactoptionalpropertytypes).  If you do so, `undefined` will no longer be added to the domain of an optional property, although you will still get a possibly `undefined` value when you read such a property:

```
type Foo = {
    x?: string,
    y: string
}

/* type Foo = {
    x?: string;
    y: string;
}*/

const foo: Foo = { y: "x" };
foo.x // string | undefined
foo.x = undefined; // error
```

And you'll get the desired behavior for the code in your example:

```
// This code is from the example in the question
f({ a: 0, b: undefined }); // error!
```

---

So that's the answer to the question as asked.  You should be aware, though, that the TS team intentionally excluded `--exactOptionalPropertyTypes` from the "standard" [`--strict` suite of compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#strict).  That's because if you enable this option by default, it would be a large breaking change in a lot of code.  Maybe if this feature had been introduced earlier, it would be fine.  But now there is plenty of existing code that also doesn't distinguish between `undefined` and missing properties very well:

```
const bar: Foo = { // error if flag enabled
    x: foo.x,
    y: foo.y
}
```

And so, depending on the rest of your code base and its dependencies, you may find it hard to just enable the feature.

[Playground link to code, `--exactOptionalPropertyTypes` off](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvAsAKCjqAPAfgC4oBnYAJwEsA7AcwBotcoQTzr6sBfLLAegBUUUJFgJkaZrkLtKtOlAA+UAK40AJhABmtCBoDc0nGzLz6RzNyiD+fTAGM4NclG0IS8RClSsSAIjx-KG5LdzgAOjwofn4zTkUVdS1dGn0scKjJZJ09Qxi4uABrAEMQeywnF2AoACMSik8JH2N8Eky8JmxcU0zyqwrMWmAICm0Sh2gAQSlunBKSGlUAW1rRyxZa4ig0gDd1nnth0fHJqAAhWZYS7b2DubrFlbWKS15MeyrXbUkACga6CQZipzgBKZAAPjQIUsAjiAHkANIZX6+BZQAAMIVBsMwsSgAFEKBQ4I0oAAVcDQADkS1Wo2pUCopB2cBqJVIpCodBoJVqABtoMBEKIaTlUvpqREUWiSBiGI9MdjcfikQraqoagBJKAAdzgqn5Gig-KoRSFiAAFiV9lASjQoKMSRQZXa5eqSOK8sqgA)

[Playground link to code, `--exactOptionalPropertytypes` on](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvAsAKCjqAPAfgC4oBnYAJwEsA7AcwBotcoQTzr6sBfLLAegBUUUJFgJkaZrkLtKtOgG5pONmXn1lmboP59MAYzg1yUAGYIS8RClSsSAIjwOo3LRbgA6PFH791nHRQAD5QAK40ACYQZrQQkVge3pIR0bE08Yq+-hAUFHAU+kYmwFAARgCGFFYSttlQufkUAIQq+CRJeEzYuGpJIDz6+rTAuWYVBtAAglI9OBUkNGEAtmW5WixlxFAZAG7rg5hYI2MT0ABCsywV23sHc+WLK2sUWrxHH8WmZpIAFFV0EgzULnACUyAAfGhXFoBP4APIAaUSvzsCygAAZXKDYZg-FAAKJ5AokAAq4GgAHIlqtcpSoFRSDs4KUKqRSFQ6DQKmUADbQYCIURU1IxOKRSmeFFokgYhiPTHY3FmVFQdFyhWi9LxJX1RoFZpQOHhKJijKRBlMmgstXszncvkCxB3ChAA)

Answer (score 0):

You can use`never` instead of `undefined`:

```
interface A {
  a: number;
  b?: never;
}

interface B {
  a?: never;
  b: number;
}
```

Comment: In my specific case I can't because the union type is a quite complex one which I generate programmatically through this utility: [RequireExactlyOne](https://github.com/sindresorhus/type-fest/blob/main/source/require-exactly-one.d.ts)

Comment: You would also need to enable [the `--exactOptionalPropertyTypes` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#exact-optional-property-types---exactoptionalpropertytypes), or else this would also accept `undefined`.

Comment: @opensorcio if you can't change your type, then what do you hope to accomplish?  You could presumably take your generated type and then map it like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w6vQRw) (assuming `--exactOptionalPropertyTypes` is enabled)?  Either way, the fact that your union is generated programmatically seems to be out of scope of the question as asked.  If you really have a hard rule that you can't modify your type (or even map it to a new type to use), then you should probably [edit] your question to specify that.

Comment: @jcalz you are right, I could have tried mapping the type, but as you said it wouldn't solve the problem.